# One is good, two can be good, three is taboo

Tags: riddle

> Using one of me is common in science and other areas,
>   but in other areas they sometimes use me the wrong way
>
> Using two of me is taboo in science, unless one of me is larger,
>  but in other areas they abuse me again by using two small variants of me
>
> Using three of me is taboo everywhere.

What am I?

Comment: Do you consider computer science a science or an other area?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I don't think that that really matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a long shot, but is it:

> The letter 'k'

Using one of me is common in science and other areas,

> k could be many things in science, such as a variable or a prefix to a unit.

but in other areas they sometimes use me the wrong way

> 'k' is sometimes used as an informal abbreviation for 'okay'.

Using two of me is taboo in science, unless one of me is larger,

> If 'k' is a variable, it would not be good to name two variables k as you couldn't tell them apart, unless one was lowercase and the other capital. If 'k' is a unit prefix, there is no unit 'kk', but there is the unit 'kK' (kilokelvin).

but in other areas they abuse me again by using two small variants of me

> The word 'kk' is also used as an informal way of saying 'okay'.

Using three of me is taboo everywhere.

> Three k's would represent the KKK, a racist organization.

Comment: You have the right answer. The k used in the wrong way refers to writing 100000 as 100k, which is common in other areas than science, but really a no go in science. What is even worse that some use 1kk for 1000000.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's taboo *everywhere*, mainly just in the US.  Other countries don't have the negative history associated with that.  I remember hearing it was the name of a supermarket chain in - Sweden I think?  Somewhere Scandinavian anyhow.